# Guava's CharSink into a backing StringBuilder?

Tags: java, guava

I'd like to expose an API that accepts a CharSink and writes to it, instead of accepting an Appendable, along the lines of:

```
public class Foo {
  public void writeTo(CharSink sink) { .. }
}
```

This would make the most common uses of the API very convenient without the regular shenanigans of opening and closing streams.

Occasionally, though, I would like to receive the output in a char sequence:

```
new Foo().writeTo(...);
CharSequence s = ...; // s now contains the chars written by writeTo
```

Is there a convenient way to use the existing method? I'll add my current approach as an answer, but I expect there are better ways.

Comment: This is something that I've thought would be a good to have, but haven't decided on a good API for. Ideally such a thing would be both a `CharSink` _and_ a `CharSource`, but given that they're abstract classes (I'd have made them interfaces with lots of default methods if they were designed for Java 8) that doesn't work. So then there's the awkward decision of "should it extend `CharSink` and have a method to get a `CharSource` view, or the other way around, or not extend either and have methods for both views?"

Comment: @ColinD agreed. Possibly a class with asCharSink and asCharSource methods.

Answer (score 3):

I currently use a class like the following:

```
public class InMemoryCharSink extends CharSink {
  private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  @Override
  public Writer openStream() throws IOException {
    return CharStreams.asWriter(sb);
  }

  public CharSequence getChars() {
    return sb;
  }
}
```

The usage would then be:

```
InMemoryCharSink sink = new InMemoryCharSink();
new Foo().writeTo(sink);
CharSequence s = sink.getChars();
```